# Object tracking in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, tracking

I had been using LK algorithm in detecting corners and interested point for tracking. 
However, I am stucked at this point where I need to have something like a rectangle box to follow the tracked object. All I have now was just a lot of points showing my moving objects.

Is there any methods or suggestions for that? Also, any idea on adding counter into the window so that my object moving in and out the screen can be counted as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [lots](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) of options!  Within OpenCV, I'd suggest using [CamShift](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#RotatedRect%20CamShift%28InputArray%20probImage,%20Rect&%20window,%20TermCriteria%20criteria%29) as a starting point, since it is a relatively easy to use.  CamShift uses mean shift to iteratively search for an object in consecutive frames.

Note that you need to seed the tracker with some kind of input.  You could have the user draw a rectangle around the object, or use a detector to get the initial input.  If you want to track faces, for example, OpenCV has a [cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier) and training data for a face detector included.

Comment: I am using it for tracking vehicles and I would like to have automatic initializing function to start detection and tracking. I was thinking to implement cvGoodFeaturesToTrack method with CamShift. Is that workable ?

Comment: @user1838245 I suppose it's possible, but Camshift is normally used with the histogram as the feature.  The features returned by good features to track are generally just strong corners, so while that is an option, it might not be that invariant to pose changes when vehicles turn.  Then again, histogram features would run into trouble when vehicles with similar colours overlap!  Lots to consider, but OpenCV makes it really easy to try different features/trackers.  Use the CascadeClassifier to detect the initial vehicle.

Comment: I was trying that as well. But I am struggling on creating a cascade for detecting what I want. Is there any good tutorials which show how to create it ?

Comment: There are plenty of explanations.  Essentially, you need a set of positive and negative examples (vehicle and not vehicle images), and then you build your classifier from these examples.  Just jumping on Google, [here is a tutorial](http://opencvuser.blogspot.ca/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html)

Comment: That means I should crop frame by frame manually for getting those images ? I had seen something like haartraining and traincascade in the apps folder in openCV folder. Does that relates to creating cascade ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  For vehicles there are probably data sets available.  Those are related, you're correct.  Hope this helps

Comment: I am looking in cvblobslib in getting the object and to be integrated with camshift. THank you

Comment: cvThreshold(gray,Threshold,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
blobs = CBlobResult(Threshold,NULL,255);
blobs.Filter(blobs,B_EXCLUDE,CBlobGetArea(),B_LESS,100);

int num_blobs = blobs.GetNumBlobs();
CBlob BiggestParameter;
CBlob LessArea;
blobs.GetNthBlob(CBlobGetPerimeter(),0,BiggestParameter);
blobs.GetNthBlob(CBlobGetArea(),blobs.GetNumBlobs()-1,LessArea);

cvMerge(Threshold,Threshold,Threshold,NULL,filter);

for(i = 0;i< num_blobs;i++)
{
currentBlob = blobs.GetBlob(i);
currentBlob->FillBlob(filter,CV_RGB(230,100,230));
}

Comment: Currently, I had done until this point and wonder how to get the bounding rectangle of the detected blob

Comment: I'm not sure and this is a tough area to read the code.  Perhaps you should ask that as a new question so it can formatted correctly